# Regex search not working

Tags: python, regex, python-2.7

I wrote a function that verifies if a specific pattern exists in a given string:

```
import re
def has_pattern(string, regex):
    if string and re.compile(regex).search(string) is not None:
        return True
    return False
```

but for some reason my test doesn't show the expected result:

```
# for absolute path on windows
pattern = '^[a-zA-Z]:\\\\[^\\\\]' # actual regex: [a-zA-Z]:\\[^\\]
path = 'a:\\' # for this result should be 'True'
print('Pattern: \'{0}\''.format(pattern))
print('Result: {0}'.format(has_pattern(path, pattern)))
```

Comment: Your regex is _requiring_ another non-\ character after the first \. Try a negative lookahead instead.

Comment: The question lacks the requirements.

Comment: I noticed this right after this post. Gosh so simple :)

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew what requirements am i missing?

Comment: You have not specified what type of strings you want to match, just one example. There can be a ton of regexps that we can offer, but they might not work with other strings you have.

Comment: Okay, it's supposed to use regular strings, not raw strings for example.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew I think his requirements are clear.  The question is about why the test string doesn't validate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your pattern is looking for a letter (upper or lowercase) at the beginning of the string followed by a colon, a backslash, and then another character which is not a backslash.

Your testing input does not end in this non-backslash character, thus does not match the pattern.

One possible pattern adaption would be:

- regex: `^[a-zA-Z]:\\(?:$|[^\\])`
- formatted for python string: `^[a-zA-Z]:\\\\(?:$|[^\\\\])`

Comment: I misinterpreted the output of my used [regex-checker](https://regex101.com/). But thanks anyway :)

Comment: Explaining that is not a solution. regex101.com can do that, too.

Comment: How is this not a solution?  He asked about why his regex wasn't validating the given input.  This is the reason why.

Comment: Then it is a dupe of [What does the regex mean](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22937618/reference-what-does-this-regex-mean).

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew So obviously referring to a `Regex`-Guide makes my question a duplicate, why is that? Please state the exact location that involves this particular problem?

Comment: There is a whole section devoted to online regex testers. Choose [regex101.com](http://regex101.com), it will tell you all about your regex.